# layered navigation / left sidebar to be floating (sticky) when you scroll the products

Tags: layered-navigation

I want to fix the layered navigation to be like a sticky header, as in when we scroll the products the filters remain as fixed and we can browse the products
like on [pepperfry.com](http://www.pepperfry.com/home-decor-garden-decor-pots-planters.html?type=clp-home-decor-bs-1).

Comment: This is sort've a general HTML/CSS question that has the same answer, regardless of platform. That said, as a tip, write a javascript to detect the length of scroll and when it hits your desired point, set the layered navigation container to ``position:fixed``

Comment: could you please be more specific as to where i have to write the script and which file do i edit thankx

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on your question like the others so I write this message as an answer.

You don't need js for this task, there is a css rule for this.

**position: sticky**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

However you may have trouble getting the rule to work in more complex layouts, so I suggest you take a look at this great resource that has always solved my problems.

https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-issues-with-css-position-sticky-not-working